# IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed with default=None, blank=True null=True in model?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am running my script in the django shell, and the error is coming from these lines:

```
new_species = Species(genus=new_genus, species=row[4])
new_species.save()
```

This error:

> IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   birds_species.species_english

I am trying to save information to this model:

```
class Species(models.Model):
    genus = models.ForeignKey(Genus, default=None)
    species = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
    species_english = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.species
```

I confirm that that migrations are up-to-date because I run the following lines in my django project:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations birds
No changes detected in app 'birds'
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, polls, auth, contenttypes, birds
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

The problem is I am trying to save an object to the Species model, without defining the 1 column `species_english`.  From the model it can be seen that I have `default=None, blank=True, null=True` which is what I thought we needed to allow null values by default.  What do I have wrong here?

I am using the default sqlite3 DB for the DB backend.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is the migration file contents:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.2 on 2016-06-17 14:02
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('birds', '0007_speciesfile'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='species',
            name='species_english',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, default=None, max_length=100, null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: can you show your migration file that defines the `species_english` field

Comment: are you quite sure you have posted the right model? I can see it producing this exception for the `species` column but not for the `species_english` column

Comment: @marcusshep Sure, i just appended that code to the question.

Comment: check your django_migrations table if this migration is in it.

Comment: @e4c5 yes I am quite sure.

Comment: Well if you leave out a value for species column it's most definitely going to throw an exception because you have set the default as None while the column doesn't allow nulls (None maps to null)

Comment: @e4c5 You can see the Error msg I have included in the question specifically indicates the field: `birds_species.species_english`

Comment: did you do this: "check your django_migrations table if this migration is in it"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114958/discussion-between-jeffery-the-wind-and-e4c5).

Comment: @e4c5 I invited you to chat if you'd like to continue to help.